# I have to define two functions related with classes

Tags: c++, class, oop

1.I have a task with a composition of classes where I have to return the hotels that have more than 10 rooms at a given address ( as an argument) I did this but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
int findHotel([], string add)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (hotels[i].getName() == na)
            hotels[i].print();
    }
}
```

2.A function that returns hotels that have at least 10 rooms that have wifi.

Comment: You could already know that what you wrote is not correct by looking at the compiler errros you get from that code. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: If you need help with code, you should include a [mcve] and the compiler errors in the question

Comment: apart from syntax errors, you are supposed to return hotels, you declared the function to return `int`, but you do not return anything, does not look quite correct...

Comment: I don't have errors, but  I'm not sure if this is the correct way?

Comment: "I don't have errors"... frankly, I do not belive that, though I also cannot convince myself, because that code will produce errors when I will try to compile it for the mere fact that it is incomplete. Please [mcve]

Comment: @HANA You need to be sure that the code you post is the same as the code you are compiling, because the code above does not compile, it has at least two errors.

Comment: Should you return them or print them? Returning things is not the same as printing things (even though we usually use "output" to refer to both).

Comment: Could you spend a little effort improving this question? For starters, there should be an actual question, with a question mark, like the first sentence of this comment. What is the actual problem that you need help with? What is wrong with what you've got for the first part? And what do you have so far (and what's wrong with it) for the second part?

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot wrong with the above.

Firstly

```
int findHotel([], string add)
```

`[]` like that is not legal syntax. I guess you meant

```
int findHotel(Hotel hotels[], string add)
```

where `Hotel` is the name of your hotel class (sorry I'm guessing but you didn't say what it is).

Secondly

```
if (hotels[i].getName() == na)
```

`na` is undeclared, I'm not sure what you meant by this. In any case your requirements are **hotels that have more than 10 rooms at a given address**. This has nothing to do with hotel names. You need something completely different in your `if` statement. Something like

```
if (hotels[i].getAddress() == add && hotels[i].getNumberOfRooms() > 10)
```

Again I'm guessing because you haven't posted the definition of you hotel class, but something along those lines.

Finally

```
hotels[i].print();
```

printing the hotel is **not** the same as returning the hotel. It's a common thing for newbies to get confused about. Returning means the function must return the data to the function caller, not print it out. So your function needs to be changed to **return**, not print, all the hotels that have a certain address and more than 10 rooms. There's lots of different ways to do that but this answer is long enough already, so look at your C++ book where it explains how to return values from functions.

The simplest way would be to put the hotels into a vector and return that.